# Start, stop and listen to a process in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, process, runtime

I want to start a process with `Runtime.exec()`. Then I want to know (listen) when the process exits. Also, I want to manually stop the process if some condition met.

The code I have now is:

```
public class ProcessManager extends Thread{
    private static ProcessManager manager;

    Process process;

    private ProcessManager(){

    }

    public static ProcessManager getInstance(){
        if(manager==null){
            manager=new ProcessManager();
        }
        return manager;
    }

    public void run(){
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        process = runtime.exec("c:\\windows\\system32\\notepad.exe");
        //cleanup();
    }
    public void cleanup(){
        //I want to do stuffs until the program really ends;
    }

    //called to manually stop the process
    public void stopProcess(){
        if(process!=null){
            //TODO: stop the process;
        }
    }
}
```

As shown in the code, my program is like `notepad.exe`, which pop up a window and immediately returns. How can I listen to the status of the program, and wait until it is closed, as well as close it explicitly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I listen to the status of the program, and wait until it is
>   closed, as well as close it explicitly?

You can use `Process#waitFor()`

```
// cause this process to stop until process p is terminated
         p.waitFor();
```

As [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29) says

> The java.lang.Process.waitFor() method causes the current thread to
>   wait, if necessary, until the process represented by this Process
>   object has terminated. This method returns immediately if the
>   subprocess has already terminated. If the subprocess has not yet
>   terminated, the calling thread will be blocked until the subprocess
>   exits.

Comment: OK. I thought programs like notepad.exe will immediately return and exit so waitfor will immediately get notified...

Comment: What made you think like that ?

Comment: I find what make me think that again... When I try "process = runtime.exec("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe"); process.waitFor();", it immedately get returned while the IE is still running.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend using Runtime.exec() directly. It is not as straightforward as it might seem. Nice article ["When Runtime.exec() won't"](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) describes these pitfalls in details. For example simple code with waitFor():

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process proc = rt.exec("javac");
int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
System.out.println("Process exitValue: " + exitVal);
```

will produce no output and hangs, because in general you need to provide handling of input, output and error streams in separate threads.

Instead you may use [Apache Commons Exec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/) library that will handle it for you:

```
String line = "notepad.exe";
CommandLine cmdLine = CommandLine.parse(line);
DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
int exitValue = executor.execute(cmdLine);
System.out.println("Process exitValue: " + exitValue);
```

Below is more complex example of asynchronous process terminated manually:

```
String line = "notepad.exe";
CommandLine cmdLine = CommandLine.parse(line);
ExecuteWatchdog watchdog = new ExecuteWatchdog(timeout);
Executor exec = new DefaultExecutor();
DefaultExecuteResultHandler handler = new DefaultExecuteResultHandler();
exec.execute(cmdLine, handler);
// wait for script to run
Thread.sleep(2000);
// terminate it manually if needed
if (someCondition) {
    watchdog.destroyProcess();
}
// wait until the result of the process execution is propagated
handler.waitFor(WAITFOR_TIMEOUT);
System.out.println("Process exitValue: " + handler.getExitValue());
```