# How to run java.lang.Process one by one?

Tags: java, process, exec

I need help in running maven command one by one through Java.

In my code I am trying to run maven build command and print the log to Swing TextArea window.
But the problem is `Process.waitFor()` is not working properly. As a result  multiple processes 
are running simultaneously and logs are not getting printed properly.
In Internet I found that `waitFor()` sometimes doesnt work. Instead I can use 
`Process.isAlive()`. But I am not sure in my code how would I use that method.
Please help

```
Timer timer =  new Timer(300, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String line;
                for (int i = 0; i < process.length; i++) {
                    BufferedReader buffer=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process[i].getInputStream()));
                    try {
                        if ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                            logTextArea[i].append(line + "\n");
                        } else {
                            ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
                        }
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    } 
                }

            }

        });
        try {
            for ( int count = 0 ; count < destList.getModel().getSize(); count++){
                String projectPath = findDir(new File(codebasePath), destList.getModel().getElementAt(count).toString());
                process[count]  = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(System.getenv("M2_HOME")+"//bin//mvn.bat clean install -DskipTests -f "+projectPath + "\\pom.xml");
                logTextArea[count] = new JTextArea(25, 60);
                logFrame[count] = new JFrame("Show Log");
                logFrame[count].add(new JScrollPane(logTextArea[count]), BorderLayout.CENTER);
                logFrame[count].setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                logFrame[count].pack();
                logFrame[count].setLocationByPlatform(true);
                logFrame[count].setVisible(true);
                timer.start();
                process[count].waitFor()
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Why do you have an array of processes if you only run one at a time anyways?

Comment: You should handle process output before calling waitFor(). This answer may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28992781/4632333

Comment: See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process. Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for things like paths containing space characters.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit puzzled where exactly you struggle, so maybe I am overlooking something, but you'd generally use it like so:

```
process[count].waitFor();
while (process[count].isAlive()) {
    Thread.sleep(100);
}
```

You might want to get rid of `waitFor` completely and add some additional checks to the loop, e.g. a timeout or a signal to cancel the process, in case the process hangs, so your application can terminate properly:

```
while (process[count].isAlive()) {
    if (someTimeoutCondition || someCancelCondition) {
        // throw exception or do whatever else you want to do in this situation to gracefully exit
    }
    Thread.sleep(100);
}
```